Refind Custom Windows Loader
I currently can manually boot on Macos and Windows.
When I boot into windows 10 It shows as "EFI Boot".
I have an EFI partition on my main SSD (NVME) with inside it \EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi
I use Refind on a USB Flashdrive.
When using Refind I can boot into Macos with a Manual Boot Stanza :
    menuentry "Mac" {
    icon \EFI\boot\icons\os_mac.png
    volume "Preboot"
    loader \3D8B1B36-C833-4C2F-912E-513AEA96ECE2\System\Library\CoreServices\boot.efi
}

However I can't boot into Windows with any generic entries (legacy,etc.) or with a Manual Boot Stanza.
No matter what I type the loader is always "incorrect" and I can't boot into Windows (from Refind)
So what should be the correct Manual Boot Stanza (especially volume and loader) to be able to launch Windows from Refind in my case ?
Or what can I do to be able to launch Windows from Refind ?
The Strangest thing is that on the same machine with Refind 0.8.3 (I currently use 0.14.2) Windows boots perfectly fine from Refind with a generic entry called "Boot Microsoft EFI boot from EFI".
Could I somehow analyse this entry and find the volume and loader values that it's using to launch windows ?
The problem is also that I have multiple EFI partitions named "EFI" on different drive on the machine. So when I select one with volume "EFI", I don't know if it's the right one that's being selected.
I tried getting the "Partition unique GUID" with gdisk (couldn't get sgdisk to work on mac, if someone knows please help) not sure it's the "unique one" but anyway I found 3 Guid Values concerning the EFI volume that I'm trying to select (1 from gdisk called "Disk Identifier (GUID) number" and 2 from Paragon Hard Disk Manager) and Refind don't recognize any of them.
So Refind recognize "EFI" as a volume (but we don't know which EFI partition it is because I have multiple one, I know it's supposed to be the 1st one, but how can I be sure of that?). Anyway Refind can never find the loader or says that the loader is invalid.
If I apply the same method and logic that I used for the MacOS Manual Boot Stanza quoted above, for Windows it should be (as there is an "EFI" folder in the "EFI" Volume :
     menuentry "Windows" {
     icon \EFI\boot\icons\os_win.png
     volume "EFI"
     loader \EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi
}

But Refind can't find "bootmgfw.efi" (although it's there if I mount the EFI partition on Mac) or says that the Loader is Invalid.
I tried multiple way to change how I indicate the loader path :
"\EFI\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi"
"\Volumes\EFI\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi"
etc. but with no success
I also tried not specifying the volume, or using GUID Value but it doesn't work.
Windows BCD
Volume List Informations
gdisk info
Refind Error
Old Refind version 0.8.3 with wrong auto-generated entries and the one I cannot remove selected

I will reiterate that I unfortunately, will be unable to help you, any information you believe is vital currently in a comment should be added to the question body. Any  ew commentary directed at me will not be seen.
